# Hugely different performance score in PageSpeed Insights and Lighthouse

Tags: pagespeed, lighthouse, pagespeed-insights

After deploying a fairly fast website, I ran it through PageSpeed Insights where it only got a performance score of around 25. At the same time, the exact same page ranks 85 in the Lighthouse performance inside Edge.

I know that the PageSpeed is likely loading the pages from the US while my hosting is located in Germany, and that the Lighthouse makes use of my connection - and since I'm much closer to the server, I likely get better results because of that.

However, with performance being one of key metrics for rating a page, I can't not ask - how is this being evaluated in the real world? Should I rely more on the US-based PageSpeed or the local Lighthouse?

Note: The page is already pretty optimized, with deferred JS, minified JS & CSS, lazy loading images, compressed images and all the other nice things.

Comment: Such vast differences are normally that you have something configured incorrectly (such as not clearing storage) or you are comparing a desktop audit to a mobile audit (which is too easy to do as it isn't clear which audit you just ran). Do you want to give me the site URL and I will test it my end (from UK) then I can help you identify if it is PSI or indeed just a setting needs changing at your side. One thing that would be really useful is if you scroll to the bottom of your lighthouse (local) report and copy all the "runtime settings" into your question.

Comment: Good advice, but I did realize that and checked that I'm not comparing desktop to mobile. The site url is https://www.logis.net - thanks in advance!

Comment: Just ran it, got 58 local and 53 page speed insights for "mobile". **But** I did get 23 for "desktop" on Page Speed Insights so perhaps you looked at that tab on Page Seed Insights. Do you want to rerun and just check that first before we look at why you get 85 locally and I only get 58?

Comment: Thanks for checking. I re-ran PSI: 52 (mobile) / 54 (desktop), which is much better than before, and in Lighthouse, it's 68/80. This is probably caused by some tweaking of the slider that I've done. However, if you'd look at https://logis.net/solutions/aps-discrete-manufacturing/, PSI would give 24/76 and Lighthouse would be 60/90.

Comment: Right so ignore my previous point, I ran lighthouse in Chrome not Edge as I missed that part in your question. In Chrome they pretty much match, in Edge they are similar to what you said. I will see if I can work it out for you but for now I would trust Page Speed Insights or Lighthouse in Google Chrome over Edge, looking at the performance with throttling on (network tab) I am afraid these are more likely to be accurate.

Comment: Right. I'm also going to run it through Pingdom and GTmetrix to see if I can find any clues.

Comment: The issue with those is they are desktop, so just bear that in mind when trying to compare.

Comment: https://web.dev/measure/ gives you 12 / 100 on one run and 24/100 on the second run (both when testing the second URL). This points to Edge "over scoring", but it also points to some server instability which will not help when trying to identify the root cause of the issue.

Comment: Seems you're right. I'll start going through recommendations from web.dev and Pingdom then.

Answer (score 1):

As this question is being read a lot I thought I would summarise the comments between OP and I into an answer.

For some reason Lighthouse in Edge is reporting a much higher score than Lighthouse in other browsers.

I checked that the settings were the same for Edge as they were in Chrome and Vivaldi and ran some tests on numerous websites.

Chrome and Vivaldi were within 10% of each other but edge was scoring as much as 200% higher scores and faster FCP times etc.

As such I would not recommend using Edge Lighthouse at time of writing as it will make you think your site is performing better than it actually is.

**More importantly** it may not show items that need fixing within the "opportunities" and "diagnostics" sections that rely on timings and although the score is not important a lot of these recommendations can be.

I will try and update this answer if the discrepancy between Edge and Other Webkit browsers changes.

Answer (score 0):

There is difference in PS scored of your website even when Checked on Chrome(normal mode and in incognito mode).
[image]

[image]

The only reason i can think of is of Cache plugin on your website. Disable and test again for PS score. Also the thing to note:

> All tests are run using a simulated mobile device, throttled to a fast 3G network & 4x CPU slowdown.
> https://web.dev/measure/

So website in general are faster than what PageSpeed shows.

Comment: I think you completely misunderstood (as I did at first), he is comparing **Lighthouse in Developer Tools** to Page Speed Insights. For Google Chrome the numbers in Lighthouse more or less match Page Speed Insights (which is what you would expect). However if you run "Lighthouse" from developer tools in Microsoft Edge the score is **significantly** higher, even with the exact same settings.

Comment: Lighthouse in Chrome and Edge are configured differently, and even within each there are operational errors in the configuration that significantly affect results. For example, Chrome flags an issue with inline css and js while running, deletes it before finishing (probably because it finds the hashes protecting them), but still penalises the Best Practices result. Edge flags resources as non-versioned if they don't use a `2.4` type format, even though the only requirement for url versioning is being uniquely different. Pinch of salt required before taking Lighthouse results at face value.